# Regex, select the line that starts with my condition, but take only the characters after space

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file that has content similiar below:

```
ptrn: 435324kjlkj34523453
Note1: rtewqtiojdfgkasdktewitogaidfks
Note2: t4rwe3tewrkterqwotkjrekqtrtlltre
```

I am trying to get characters after space at the line starts with "ptrn:" . I am trying the command below ;

`>>> cat daily.txt | grep '^p.*$' > dailynew.txt`

and I am getting the result in the new file:

```
ptrn: 435324kjlkj34523453
```

But I want only the characters after space, which are " **435324kjlkj34523453**" to be written in the new file without "**ptrn:**" at the beginning.

The result should be like:

```
435324kjlkj34523453
```

How can establish this goal with an efficient regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -oP '^ptrn:\s*\K.*' daily.txt > dailynew.txt
awk '/^ptrn:/{print $2}' daily.txt > dailynew.txt
sed -n 's/^ptrn:[[:space:]]*\(.*\)/\1/p' daily.txt > dailynew.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/J1tWpb). All output `435324kjlkj34523453`.

In the `grep` PCRE regex (enabled with `-P` option) the patterns match

- `^` - the startof string
- `ptrn:` - a `ptrn:` substring
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that clears the current match value
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

In the `awk` command, `^ptrn:` regex is used to find the line starting with `ptrn:` and then `{print $2}` prints the value after the first whitespace, from the second "column" (since the default field separator in `awk` is whitespace).

In `sed`, the command means

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `s` - substitution command is used
- `^ptrn:[[:space:]]*\(.*\)` - start of string, `ptrn:`, zero or more whitespace, and the rest of the line captured into Group 1
- `\1` - replaces the match with group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/^ptrn: (.*)/\1/p' file > output_file.txt
```

Comment: where do I need to point input file, which is in example daily.txt ?

Comment: you use `>` to redirect output to a file and then the file name.